# Extra checkbox in datagrid listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a test application and require a checkbox to be placed next to each item in the datagrid.

The issue I found is that right next to the last row in the grid, I was getting an extra checkbox. The way to remove this issue after searching properly on the web is to do the following.
Edited the datagrid properties and added the CanUserAddRow property, set to false.

Added CanUserAddRows="False" to the DAtagrid properties to resolve the issue. <DataGrid x:Name="GridName" CanUserAddRows="False/>

[image]

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="DGServerList"  Grid.Column="2"  SelectionChanged="datagrid_selection"  HorizontalAlignment="left"  Height="365"  Width="625" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="9,159,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.ColumnSpan="8" SelectedItem="{Binding PopulateDataGrid, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  x:Name="chkSelectedServer" Binding="{Binding IsChecked}"  Header="Choose"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding ServerId}"  Header="ServerId"/>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: That should be a setting on the datagrid itself, try looking for a flag (boolean) property related to adding new rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [CanUserAddRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows?view=net-5.0) to false on your `DataGrid`. The default is true, which causes the display of an additional row at the bottom of the grid.

Comment: That did the trick, not sure why I was looking for AllowUserToAddRows.. Thanks again